# Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains a single, compatible version of javax.persistence.Table

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

An attempt was made to call a method that does not exist. The attempt was made from the following location:

    org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.EntityBinder.processComplementaryTableDefinitions(EntityBinder.java:1236)

The following method did not exist:

    javax.persistence.Table.indexes()[Ljavax/persistence/Index;

The method''s class, javax.persistence.Table, is available from the following locations:

    jar:file:/C:/jboss-eap-6.4.0/jboss-eap-6.4/modules/system/layers/base/javax/persistence/api/main/hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final-redhat-3.jar!/javax/persistence/Table.class
    vfs:/C:/jboss-eap-6.4.0/jboss-eap-6.4/bin/content/bancaws.war/WEB-INF/lib/javax.persistence-api-2.2.jar/javax/persistence/Table.class

It was loaded from the following location:

    jar:file:/C:/jboss-eap-6.4.0/jboss-eap-6.4/modules/system/layers/base/javax/persistence/api/main/hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final-redhat-3.jar!/


Action:

Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains a single, compatible version of javax.persistence.Table
```

Please help to resolve the above the issue.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
   <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
   <groupId>xxxx</groupId>
   <artifactId>xxxx</artifactId>
   <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
   <packaging>war</packaging>
   <parent>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
      <version>2.1.7.RELEASE</version>
   </parent>
   <dependencies>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
         <version>2.1.7.RELEASE</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
         <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
         <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
      </dependency>
      <!-- testing dependency -->
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
         <scope>test</scope>
         <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
               <groupId>junit</groupId>
               <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
         </exclusions>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
         <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
         <version>5.3.2</version>
         <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
         <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
         <version>5.3.2</version>
         <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>
      <!--Oracle JDBC -->
      <dependency>
         <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
         <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
         <version>18.3</version>
      </dependency>
      <!-- HikariCP connection pool -->
      <dependency>
         <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
         <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
         <version>2.6.0</version>
      </dependency>
      <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-web -->
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
         <version>5.1.9.RELEASE</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>javax</groupId>
         <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
         <version>8.0</version>
         <scope>provided</scope>
      </dependency>
   </dependencies>
   <build>
      <finalName>xxxx</finalName>
      <plugins>
         <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.0</version>
            <configuration>
               <source>1.8</source>
               <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
         </plugin>
         <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.1</version>
            <configuration>
               <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
            </configuration>
         </plugin>
         <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.22.0</version>
         </plugin>
      </plugins>
   </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Can you please provide more details on your application stack?

Comment: I am new to springboot application. I created a new application and trying to deploy the war file in jboss server 6.4 version. while deploying i facing the above error. i will attach my pom file.

Comment: There are a couple of problems with your pom.xml. By default, Springboot will try to load the project on embedded tomcat during start up. If you plan to run this project on jboss, you need to exclude that from the dependency tree. Also, are you using a SpringBootServletInitializer to define the application entry point in the right manner?

Comment: Yes,i am using SpringBootServletInitializer to define the application.

Comment: I excluded the tomcat from the dependency tree. Facing same error.
Below pom.xml
      <dependency>
             <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
             <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
             <exclusions>
                 <exclusion>
                     <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                     <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                 </exclusion>
             </exclusions>
         </dependency>

Comment: It is due to version conflict between hibernate jpa jars. Since you have mentioned that you are new to springboot application, I would suggest you to first create a springboot starter web project which has a main class and can be invoked through command line using mvn springboot:run to see it running on embedded tomcat before trying to deploy the war generated on a different container. In this way, a lot can be learnt. Just my two cents..

Answer (score 3):

This error is caused due to version conflict of dependency jars. I found that you are using hibernate-jpa-2.1-api in your pom.xml and it is conflicting with the following as your error message says:

```
jar:file:/C:/jboss-eap-6.4.0/jboss-eap-6.4/modules/system/layers/base/javax/persistence/api/main/hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final-redhat-3.jar!/
```

It seems to me that your JBoss version supports hibernate jpa version 2.0. So if you are not explicitly using any interfaces out of the 2.1 jpa version in your code, you can try to remove the following dependency:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
```

If you intend to use jpa version 2.1, probably you need to deploy your war into a web container that supports that version.

Comment: Kavitha, Thanks u so much for your answer and quick response. Now its working fine.